# I keep getting "None" in beautiful soup for every website that I try to scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was just trying to do a simple weather app and I was trying the scrape open weather by getting the tag of the weather but it kept saying

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

If I remove the .span it just says None which is also not what I want.
I was expecting to get the html tag printed out. I'm not sure what's going wrong, also if I remove the span it just says none.

code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://openweathermap.org/city/4930956" #url for the city that im getting the weeather from

page = requests.get(url).text #using requets
doc = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser") #reading the document with beautifulsoup

temperature = doc.find(class_="heading") #getting the temperature value which is in the heading class with the span tag

print(temperature) #printing the tag
```

Comment: Use OpenWheather APIs

Comment: Learn [how to format a literal block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Beyond that nitpick you should avoid web scraping when a sane API is available. As suggested by the answer you dismissed. You should accept that answer.

Comment: Scraping a web site is now much more complicated than it used to be given the prevalence of AJAX. You have to use something like Selenium to evaluate the content of the returned page (i.e., the Javascript) like a browser would do. But, as I said in my previous comment, examining a web page when a sane API for getting the data exists is silly.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but they have an api https://openweathermap.org/api
Looks like the api is free to use for less than a thousand queries per day.

You might be experiencing some anti-scraping stuff from them, as they want people to access their data either through the api or as a normal person looking at the website.

Can't reply to your question as I don't have enough rep lol

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reponse, yep I saw that they have an api, but I wanted to learn web scraping using beautiful soup and requests, so that's why. But thank you.

Comment: @NOGPOG I ran this locally, what you're running into is dynamically loaded content. The temperature is loaded dynamically.

I assume you went inspect element on the temperature and saw that it had the class "heading". See that it's a child of <div id='weather-widget'>? Debug that code or just print(page) and see that the weather widget div begins empty.

What you need is selenium to load the web page fully before trying to parse it. I haven't read this guide, but it seems applicable. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-scrape-dynamic-web-pages-with-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-fa593235981